# Is it safe to unplug one end of the HDMI cable but leave the other end connected to the PC?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, power-supply, hdmi

Because of the quarantine and Home offices, I need to frequently connect my personal monitor to my work notebook. I know that HDMI ports aren't very durable so I really don't want to disconnect the cable from the graphics card, but is it safe to do so? If put a "cap" on the free end of the HDMI cable, do I need to turn off the PSU? (I know you shouldn't be turning the PSU off and on again frequently)

Please let me know if the question makes sense I will try to elaborate further

Answer (score 1):

As long as the disconnected end of the HDMI cable isn't going to get trodden on, ridden over or dunked into water/coffee/chai latte/insert other drink here; you're fine. You don't need to turn off the PSU.

HDMI cables ARE pretty robust, and worst case you can order a new cable. They're relatively inexpensive.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.     
Nah, the cable shouldn't be in any danger I am not worried about that, just mainly the HDMI port and the GPU. It's relatively cheap to replace a cable than to replace a whole GPU.

Comment: Then wind the cable into a loose loop and tuck it behind the case, ensuring the connector remains at 90° to the case/port on the graphics card. Or, get a short male to female HDMI cable as a short extender, and plug in/out of the extender, leaving the connector in the HDMI port in-situ.

Comment: Yeah I bought a port saver for the monitor, using it exactly like you mentioned. If it is ok to leave the PSU on, I won't need to unplug from the GPU, this saves me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The maximum voltage you'll find in an HDMI cable is **5V** on Pin 18 which is mainly used when connecting a MHL-compatible device to your monitor.

Since that is extra-low voltage you do not have any risk of hurting people. 
Other than that a plastic cap would also eliminate the risk of conductive materials getting inside the connector.

Comment: Thank you.
I luckily do have  cap, so hopefully nothing bad will happen to the GPU or PSU, even if I don't power it down